# ASP.NET MVC Action Parameters with Binded prefix not compatible with Url.Route in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a details page containing a form field named UserId. On the same page i have another search form with a field also named UserId.

I am using Html.LabelFor(vm > vm.UserId) and Html.TextBoxFor(sm > sm.UserId) on the two different view models, vm being the view model and sm being the search model. (Yes, the UserId property on the two models has identical names - because they are the same domain property.

When i navigate to the page, the populated UserId on the vm is inserted into BOTH form fields named UserId by MVC. Even the sm.UserId are empty.

That is my initial problem. There are a few ways ti avoid that. My solution was to use the Prefix flag for the sm.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Search([Bind(Prefix = "Search")] SearchFormViewModel searchFormViewModel, PagingViewModel pagingViewModel)
    {
```

This will provoke MVC to render a Search.UserId on the fieldname in the search form, but the property in code will still be named UserId.

This solution seems to work great!

BUT:
Now i have to address the search.UserId on a route from Global.asax.
I map the route like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "MyRouteName",
            "ControllerName/User/{Search.UserId}",
            new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "Search" }
            );
```

My problem is that MVC can't map the Search.UserId (because of the .) to fit the UserId (prefixed with Search) in the action shown above.

So it seems like MVC has a prefix-feature, that are actually nok fully supported through the Route-handler.

Ofcourse i could rename the Search.UserId to Search_UserId, but then the name dosent match the name MVC expects in the recieving action above. (expects Search.UserId) Renaming The UserId property of the search model would fix the issue, but since it is the same value in the domain, this seems like a workaround.

Am I missing something here about the usage of the Prefix feature or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I've been thinking about this for a while now. - And a colleague of mine suddently showed me the light.

The problem lies where MVC maps the object to a route dictionary.

```
<a href="<%: Url.RouteUrl("MyRouteName", new { Search.UserId = Model.UserId } ) %>" target="_blank">See the user</a>
```

wount work. Because MVC can not handle the .(dot) in the object name.

- but since the object name is just a string key in the routevaluedictionary, mapping it my self did the trick:

  `<a href="<%: Url.RouteUrl("MyRouteName", new RouteValueDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object>(){ "Search.UserId", Model.UserId })) %>" target="_blank">See the user</a>`

Comment: The last line of code was jinx'ed because it thought it was a link . even though i used code-tags. But here it is: <a href="<%: Url.RouteUrl("MyRouteName", new RouteValueDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object>(){ "Search.UserId", Model.UserId })) %>" target="_blank">See the user</a>